# How to preserve the content of an ignored folder in Git

Tags: git, project, directory

I have a folder name: 'create_assets', where I store my source files of images and other media, like psd's.

I don't want this to be included in my Git project so the folder is ignored. However during a push/pull sync last week I lost all the contents of that folder.

I was unable to recover the folder and files.
Do I just keep this 'create_assets' folder out of my project folder or can I keep it secure without stopping to ignore it?

Comment: Can you describe what you do in a "push/pull sync". Unless you explicitly tell it to clean, git shouldn't remove ignore files (although it might do if you switch to a branch where previously ignored files are replaced with tracked versions).

Comment: I think that's exactly what happened. I did a lot of branch switching and the next day when I checked, I noticed my folder was gone, I couldn't revert.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a .gitignore to the folder with a single '*'
It will ignore the contents while keeping the folder in the repo.

Comment: Do you mean inside my "create_assets" folder? Or in the projects .gitinore file like this:
`create_assets/*`

Comment: Inside the folder. You can force any folder into the repo by creating an empty .gitignore inside it. Since you want to ignore the folder contents, a single * in the file should do it.

Answer (score 1):

You could also just initialize a git repo and place it there. That would also allow you to keep that directory and version it as well.

Comment: Init another git inside the folder?

Comment: yes. but you might have to do that outside and then copy it in.